# Checking the progress of a video uploading to YouTube - Unpublished Videos

Tags: c#-4.0, youtube-api

Is there a url I can go to to check the status of video I am uploading to YouTube via the API?

I went to this page

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_checking_video_status

which told me to go to this URL

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users//uploads

But all I got back is an RSS feed of videos that are already uploaded (Published).

I am looking for unpublished videos and the associated progress.

I am using resumable upload so I am think if 10% of the video got uploaded I should be able to see that somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

In Java sample you can request progress status via MediaHttpUploader.getProgress() or MediaHttpUploader.getNumBytesUploaded() "https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/java/youtube-cmdline-uploadvideo-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/youtube_cmdline_uploadvideo_sample/UploadVideo.java#213"

C# would be really similar.